# SQL column sorting by value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, multiple-columns

Using T-SQL I'm creating a temp table grid. I need to reorder the columns based on the total of the column starting with the largest.

For example

```
----    DO  MO  BC  NI  SC
Total   22  44  53  57  24
Prod A  0   24  0   24   0
Prod B  0   0   0   20   7
Prod C  0   20  0   13  13
```

Would become:

```
----    NI  BC  MO  SC  DO
Total   57  53  44  24  22
Prod A  24   0  24   0   0
Prod B  20   0   0   7   0
Prod C  13   0  20  13   0
```

Comment: perhaps you can enclose case logic into a function.

Comment: How are you creating the first table?

Comment: Are these (`----    DO  MO  BC  NI  SC`) values or column names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of, `----` if a terrible column name but I could think of no better for this so I kept it.

You can build the query dynamically where you sort the columns when you build the query string.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = '
select [----]'+
  (
  select ', '+T2.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)')
  from (
       select DO, MO, BC, NI, SC
       from T
       where [----] = 'Total'
       for xml path(''), type
       ) as T1(X)
  cross apply T1.X.nodes('*') as T2(N)
  order by T2.N.value('.', 'int') desc
  for xml path('')
  )+'
from T'

exec (@SQL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fb9d/1)

**Update**

If you think the XML version of building the dynamic query is a bit complicated and unintuitive you can use this instead, totally void of XML stuff.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
declare @Col nvarchar(128)

declare C cursor local fast_forward for
  select U.Col
  from (
       select DO, MO, BC, NI, SC
       from T
       where [----] = 'Total'
       ) as T
  unpivot(Val for Col in (DO, MO, BC, NI, SC)) as U
  order by U.Val desc

set @SQL = 'select [----]'

open C
fetch next from C into @Col
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  set @SQL = @SQL + ',' + @Col
  fetch next from C into @Col
end

close C
deallocate C

set @SQL = @SQL + ' from T'

exec (@SQL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5fb9d/2)

Comment: I'm accepting this because it would work. It doesn't for me because the SQL environment I'm limited to doesn't let me do an EXEC or call another stored proc. Since all the elements are included in the column (including the titles), I will designate each as a string with part to the left being the sort value and part to the right being the display value. So, kind of like a multidimensional string array. To me this is easier than doing a lot of other things.

Answer (score 1):

If is is a temp table you could:

1. create it
2. calculate the column order
3. create another table with the correct order
4. insert into that table (in the correct order)

But I still have to ask why?

You do know you can order the columns in a select statement?

Do do know how to sum the columns?

```
select sum(col1), sum(col2) 
from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot reorder columns in SQL.

Comment: you could probably do it with some wild PIVOT/ UNPIVOT stuff, but... yeah, not a hot idea.